# Create Score Rank with Symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to build a score rank, transforming the score into symbols.

To do that I'm using the code from [SOURCE CODE](https://kuppalli.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/convert-amount-in-numbers-to-words/)

What I need to do and just can't is make it applicable to more than one time. I needed like to be something such as `ID+1 / ID+2` , etc. so I could apply it to all the contestants.

I've my [pen here](http://codepen.io/flavioccf/pen/wGPPvr)

```
function test_skill() {
    var junkVal=document.getElementById('score').value;
    junkVal=Math.floor(junkVal);
    var obStr=new String(junkVal);
    numReversed=obStr.split("");
    actnumber=numReversed.reverse();

    if(Number(junkVal) >=0){
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        alert('wrong Number cannot be converted');
        return false;
    }
    if(Number(junkVal)==0){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=obStr+''+'';
        return false;
    }
    if(actnumber.length>9){
        alert('Oops!!!! the Number is too big to covertes');
        return false;
    }

    var iWords=["Zero", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>"];
    var ePlace=["<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i><i class='fa fa-moon-o fa-lg'></i>"];
    var tensPlace=['dummy', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-lg"></i>' ];
    var hundredsPlace=['dummy', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-lg"></i>'];

    var iWordsLength=numReversed.length;
    var totalWords="";
    var inWords=new Array();
    var finalWord="";
    j=0;
    for(i=0; i<iWordsLength; i++){
        switch(i)
        {
        case 0:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1 ) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            inWords[j]=inWords[j]+'';
            break;
        case 1:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 2:
            if(actnumber[i]==0) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else if(actnumber[i-1]!=0 && actnumber[i-2]!=0) {
                inWords[j]=hundredsPlace[actnumber[i]]+'';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=hundredsPlace[actnumber[i]]+'';
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            if(actnumber[i+1] != 0 || actnumber[i] > 0){
                inWords[j]=inWords[j]+" Thousand";
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 5:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1) {
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            if(actnumber[i+1] != 0 || actnumber[i] > 0){
                inWords[j]=inWords[j]+"";
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        case 7:
            if(actnumber[i]==0 || actnumber[i+1]==1 ){
                inWords[j]='';
            }
            else {
                inWords[j]=iWords[actnumber[i]];
            }
            inWords[j]=inWords[j]+" Crore";
            break;
        case 8:
            tens_complication();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }

    function tens_complication() {
        if(actnumber[i]==0) {
            inWords[j]='';
        }
        else if(actnumber[i]==1) {
            inWords[j]=ePlace[actnumber[i-1]];
        }

        else if (actnumber[i]==2) {
            inWords[j]=ePlace[actnumber[i-2]];
        }

        else {
            inWords[j]=tensPlace[actnumber[i]];
        }


    }
    inWords.reverse();
    for(i=0; i<inWords.length; i++) {
        finalWord+=inWords[i];
    }
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML=finalWord;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please give some expected input and output.

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/thdk/pen/pydpGN?editors=1010 I can go into detail later but running out of time here to pick up the lady ;)

Comment: @Thdk thanks for it! I think that that's gonna work!

Comment: Alright, I just posted my answer using the code from my earlier pen. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a pen that might be what you are looking for.

My solution allows to create multiple input fields in html.

The html used in my solution looks like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="score" value="10" />
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="score" value="25" />
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="score" value="5" />
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="score" value="7" />
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="sr1" value="Click Here" onClick="go()" />
```

When you click the button. The jquery function "each" will loop all these input boxes and execute the code you wrote already for each of them.

```
function go() {
  $("input[name=score]").each(function() {
    test_skill($(this));
  });
}
```

The above function will call your test_skill function for every input box and passes the input box as a parameter.

So change your function test_skill now to use the value from the input box passed as a parameter.

```
function test_skill(input) {
  var junkVal = input.val();
  // some more code you wrote already
}
```

Finally we need a 'container' element to display the result for every input box. Using the html I provided we can find the correct container div and fill it with the result with this code:

```
function test_skill(input) {
// more code here
// replace your last line of test_skill with the line below
input.parent().find(".container").html(finalWord);
}
```

You can see the result in this pen: http://codepen.io/thdk/pen/pydpGN?editors=1010

I hope this can help you.